# Custom spring-data repository backend

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I already have a working object storage service, developed in-house - let's call it a database. Now I would like to use spring-data for CRUD operations on it, so that in the future I can easily switch to some conventional database.
The question in: how can I implement yet another spring-data repository backend? Any guides, tutorials?

Comment: could you rephrase your question? It's not clear to me what you're trying to do and what problem you have.

Comment: Let's just say I have a database which is not supported by spring-data and I want to use it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'not supported'? is that a relational database? you can try to implement your own JPA Provider, read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350493/creating-a-jpa-provider).

Comment: Well exactly "not supported" - not a relational, not a mongodb, not a couchdb, not a redis, but something else. ie not listed on http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/

Comment: @milan Could you please provide a code of your solution, if you did that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The central piece to look at is the API in the [Spring Data Commons](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons) module. It effectively provides the foundation for all of the existing store implementations. The support consist of the following aspects:

- Object-to-store mapping (meta-model and conversion implementation)
- Repository implementation and DI container configuration support

The best way to get started is by having a look at the [MongoDB module](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb) for example and mimic the implementation. We're currently working on a developer guide whose work-in-progress version you can find in the [Spring Data Commons wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Developer-guide).

Comment: A bit sad to see that even 5 years later the wiki page still has a lot of TODOs...